# How to read Stdout from failed command

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I have the following code to check if an SSH connection to a given host is working.

```golang
func IsSSHConnectionWorking(Host Host) bool {
    cmd :=
        fmt.Sprintf("ssh -o \"PasswordAuthentication no\" -i %s -p %s %s@%s", Host.IdentityFile, Host.Port, Host.User, Host.IP)

    fmt.Printf("Connecting to %s with %s", Host.IP, cmd)

    output, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", cmd).Output()

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        log.Printf("Failed to connect to Host: %s\n Error: %s", Host.IP, output)
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

I have noted though that should a parameter be wrong, the err that is returned back into the program is `exit status 255` and the output is empty.

Executing a problematic command on the CLI itself will return `user@host: Permission denied (publickey,password).`

Is there a way to capture this?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#ExitError.Stderr

Comment: Why not use golang.org/x/crypto/ssh directly?

Comment: And if you're going to fork to ssh, why do it via `bash -c`?

Comment: Using ssh from golang is unnecessary at this point. Id rather go with the battle proven version of my system. `bash -c` is used to make use of pipes for more complex commands.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use `CombinedOutput` instead, as this will capture both stdout and stderr. Meanwhile, `Output` only returns stdout.

https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.CombinedOutput

If you want to still use Output, please cast the error to ExitError and check ExitError.Stderr as well.

https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Output